# Reduce Google OAuth 2.0 token time-to-live with Google.Apis.Auth library (C#) for debugging purposes

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

The token lasts for an hour which is quite long for me if I want to debug refresh_token mechanism. Is there any way to reduce this time to make it expire in a minute? I'm using Google.Apis.Auth library in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry you can not change the lifespan of access token. But you can refresh access token as well although the access token haven't expired yet.